# Hbase TimeSeries data distribution

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have hbase table with following fields.

**Row Key -**

UniqueID#SensorID#Timestamp

**Columns -**

- sensor_id
- Metric
- value
- timestamp

I am pushing data in every minute to this hbase table.My hbase clusters includes two region servers for storing data.

Is there any way to distribute data particular region server for a particular time duration and add new data nodes to the cluster as data increases?

Comment: When regions becomes too big, HBase splits them (according to a policy that can be specified per table). If you have added new Region Servers to you cluster HBase should assign those regions to the new servers. You cannot control distribution per Region Servers according to time duration.
I’m also skeptical regarding your RowRey design. Have a look at http://opentsdb.net/ which is a TimeSeries implementation on top of HBase

Comment: @Harold Thanks for the details